# Get total record count in Lucene or SQL SERVER Full Text Search

Tags: sql-server, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

I have a table named `Tags`. Within this table I have a `ID`, an `tag name`.
I would like to find total record count by group by when user type in some `prefix words` in  a web page textbox.
Same as stackoverflow.com.

when user type in `"sql"` word ,the result below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From a Lucene index, you can get the number of document containing a term (docfreq), using [IndexReader.docfreq](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#docFreq%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef%29), such as:

```
reader.docfreq("tags", new BytesRef("sql"));
```

This will require a precise term value (no wildcards).  You should perform your wildcard search normally, and make a call to docfreq, as above, for each result displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that would work. Note that a leading wildcard can be **VERY** slow on a large index.

```cs
RAMDirectory dir = new RAMDirectory();
IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(dir, new KeywordAnalyzer(), IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

Document d = new Document();
Field f = new Field("tag", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
d.Add(f);

f.SetValue("sql");
iw.AddDocument(d);
f.SetValue("mysql");
iw.AddDocument(d);
f.SetValue("sql-server");
iw.AddDocument(d);
f.SetValue("sql-server");
iw.AddDocument(d);
f.SetValue("sql-server");
iw.AddDocument(d);
f.SetValue("c#");
iw.AddDocument(d);
f.SetValue("java");
iw.AddDocument(d);
f.SetValue("java");
iw.AddDocument(d);

iw.Commit();
IndexReader reader = iw.GetReader();
Console.WriteLine("Tags containing sql");
using (FilteredTermEnum termEnum = new WildcardTermEnum(reader, new Term("tag", "*sql*")))
{
    do
    {
        if (termEnum.Term != null)
            Console.WriteLine(termEnum.Term.Text + ":" + reader.DocFreq(termEnum.Term));
    }
    while (termEnum.Next());
}
Console.WriteLine("\nTags containing java");
using (FilteredTermEnum termEnum = new WildcardTermEnum(reader, new Term("tag", "*java*")))
{
    do
    {
        if (termEnum.Term != null)
            Console.WriteLine(termEnum.Term.Text + ":" + reader.DocFreq(termEnum.Term));
    }
    while (termEnum.Next());
}
reader.Dispose();
iw.Dispose();
```